# Limiting the number of rows in Grails Pagination Issue

Tags: grails, pagination, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-controller

[image: Data Activity monitor]

Hi,

As shown in the image above, I have the rows and pagination doesnt work properly as expected. Instead of showing 10 records per page(look at the pagination code below), it shows all the records in the same page and same record is showing in all the pages.

here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<g:applyLayout name="protocolNavigator">
<meta name="layout" content="page" />
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<g:resource dir="BI/d3" file="d3.v2.js"/>"></script>
    </head>
    <content tag="listTitle">
        <label>Data Activity</label>
    </content>
    <content tag="list">    
    <div id="div_print">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tablesorter">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Study Id</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Start Time</th>
                        <th>Scheduler Name</th>
                        <th>Activity Description</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <g:each in="${data}">
                        <tr>
                            <td><g:remoteLink action="show" controller="DailyJobActivity" params='[id:"${it?.id}", name:""]' update="[success:'dataBox',failure:'error']" onSuccess="showDataBox()">${it?.study?.name}</g:remoteLink></td>
                            <!-- <td>${it?.provider}</td> -->
                            <td><g:remoteLink action="show" controller="DailyJobActivity" params='[id:"${it?.id}", name:""]' update="[success:'dataBox',failure:'error']" onSuccess="showDataBox()"><g:formatDate format="MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm" date="${it?.last_activity_datetime}"/></g:remoteLink></td>
                            <td><g:remoteLink action="show" controller="DailyJobActivity" params='[id:"${it?.id}", name:""]' update="[success:'dataBox',failure:'error']" onSuccess="showDataBox()"><g:formatDate format="MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm" date="${it?.started_datetime}"/></g:remoteLink></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><g:remoteLink action="show" controller="DailyJobActivity" params='[id:"${it?.id}", name:""]' update="[success:'dataBox',failure:'error']" onSuccess="showDataBox()">${it?.job}</g:remoteLink></td>
                            <td><g:remoteLink action="show" controller="DailyJobActivity" params='[id:"${it?.id}", name:""]' update="[success:'dataBox',failure:'error']" onSuccess="showDataBox()">${it?.current_status}</g:remoteLink></td>
                        </tr>
                    </g:each>
                </tbody>
            </table>
             </div>
        </content>
</g:applyLayout>
```

DailyJobActivity Controller is shown below.

### BottomOptionsNone:

```
<div class="bottoMenu">
    <div class="pg">    
        <g:if test="${instanceTotal != null}">
            <g:if test="${remotePagination == true}">
                <util:remotePaginate action="${params.action}" params="${params}" total="${instanceTotal}" maxsteps="10" onSuccess="showDataBox()" update="[success:'dataBox',failure:'error']" /> 
            </g:if>
            <g:else>
                <g:paginate maxsteps="10" action="${params.action}" total="${instanceTotal}" params="${params}"/>
            </g:else>
        </g:if>
    </div>
</div>
```

### RemotePagination Script :

```
<script>remotePagination
                if (typeof (hideMsg) != "undefined")
                    hideMsg()
            </script>
```

### In protocolnavigator :

```
        <g:applyLayout name="bottomOptionsnone">
```

### DailyJobActivity Controller

```
package com.datumrite.sdtm
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import com.datumrite.master.*;
import com.datumrite.BaseController
import com.datumrite.sdtm.Dailyjob


@Mixin(BaseController)
class DailyJobActivityController {
    def commonService;
    def view_name='/dataManagement/DailyJob'
    def protoId 
    def providerId
    def index() { }

    def show(){
        System.out.println "=== Activity ===";
        def data = []
        def job = Dailyjob.get(params.id as Long);
        data = Dailyjobactivity.where { 
        daily_job == job  
        }.list([sort:'activity_datetime',order:'desc'])
        System.out.println "=== Data ==="+data;
        render(view:view_name+'/jobactivity',model:[data:data,instanceTotal:data.size()])
    } 
}
```

I have given the maxsteps as 10 .. and called accordingly.. But it is not getting reflected.

I want the no. of rows to be 10.. but it is more in this page as you see above.

can anyone help ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: this be your controller then which you have not provided: https://github.com/vahidhedayati/mailinglist/blob/master/grails-app/views/mailingList/_listing.gsp#L49 take a look at how this controller is working as you can see with remotepagination as pointed out on line 49 in above link https://github.com/vahidhedayati/mailinglist/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugin/mailinglist/core/MailingListController.groovy#L43-L89

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Documentation](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tags/paginate.html)

> maxsteps (optional) - The number of steps displayed for pagination (defaults to 10). Used ONLY if params.maxsteps is empty

Note `maxStep` is used for determining the number of *pagination links* not *number of items/records*.

For that you have to `max`, again from the documentation

> max (optional) - The number of records to display per page (defaults to 10). Used ONLY if params.max is empty

The important thing about `max` is if there is a `params.max` exists then `g:paginate` will ignore this attribute. `g:paginate` puts some properties like `max` for *number of records in per page*, `offset` for *beginning index of records* etc in `params`. You have to use those while querying for data. For example your controller code can be li following

```
    def show(){
    System.out.println "=== Activity ===";
    def data = []
    def job = Dailyjob.get(params.id as Long);

    //preparing max and offset from params
    Integer max = params.max ? params.int("max") : 10
    Integer offset = params.offset ? params.int("offset") : 0

    data = Dailyjobactivity.where { 
        daily_job == job  
    }.list([sort:'activity_datetime', order:'desc', max: max, offset: offset])

    System.out.println "=== Data ==="+data;
    render(view:view_name+'/jobactivity',model:[data:data,instanceTotal:data.size()])
}
```

Comment: I even tried using max instead of maxSteps .. it is not working out

Comment: Please post the code where you are fetching the records from db and populating the view model

Comment: Ashraf Purno - that is what I posted in beginning of the code in this post

Comment: Ashraf Purno - I have posted the code - dailyjobcontroller from where i am fetching the data

Comment: You are fetching all the data. `g:paginate` puts some properties like `max`, `offset` etc. in `params`. You have to use those in your query. I am updating my answer...

Comment: can you brief your answer Ashraf.. i m not getting u

Comment: Updated the answer, please take a look.